# funcion para dividir por 2 una lista

Tags: python

estoy tratando de crear una funcion para dividir por dos solo los numeros pares de ellos y agregarlos a una lista el codigo es:

```
resultado_mitad = []
resultado_mitad_mitad = []
uno=[17, 20, 22, 27, 31, 46]

def mitad(lista):
    resultado_mitad.append([i for i in lista if not i % 2 and i <= 50])
    return resultado_mitad


a = mitad(uno)
print(a)


def mitad_mitad(mitad):

    if len(a) == 1:
        medio_uno = uno[0]/2
    if len(a):
        medio_uno = uno[0]//2
        medio_dos = uno[1]//2
    if len(a):
        medio_uno = uno[0]//2
        medio_dos = uno[1]//2
        medio_tres = uno[2]//2
    return medio_uno, medio_dos, medio_tres


print(mitad_mitad(a))
```

pero la primera funcion me  devulve [[20, 22, 46]]
que es lo que quiero y la segunda funcion me devuelve (8, 10, 11)
porque me devuelve 8 ?
como podria hacerlo en una sola funcion?
gracias

Comment: te devuelve eso por que `17//2=8`, `20//2=10`, `22//2=11`. Quieres quedarte con todos los elementos de la lista (y dividir los pares) o solo quedarte con los pares (ya divididos)??

Comment: tu funcion mitad_mitad recibe como parametro mitad, pero dentro de ella usas la lista uno que es la lista completa, en lugar de usar la lista pasada por parametro...

Answer (score 0):

Te estas enredando con los if y las funciones. La lógica de programación debe fluir de forma natural:

```
def dividir_pares(lista):
    res = []
    for elem in lista: # por cada elemento de la lista
        if not elem % 2: # si el elemento actual es par
            res.append(elem // 2) # agregar la mitad del elemento a res
    return res
```

Otra forma [más pythonica](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) de escribir lo mismo:

```
def dividir_pares(lista):
    return [x//2 for x in lista if not x%2]
```